# unique array on base on value of specific key

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [hotelID] => 10
        [hotelcategoryID] => 12
        [hotelName] => Grand Forest Metsovo
        [hotelShortDescription] => 
        [hotelVisible] => 1
        [roomID] => 2
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [hotelID] => 10
        [hotelcategoryID] => 12
        [hotelName] => Grand Forest Metsovo
        [hotelShortDescription] => 
        [hotelVisible] => 1
        [roomID] => 3
    )

    [2] => Array
    (
        [hotelID] => 10
        [hotelcategoryID] => 12
        [hotelName] => Grand Forest Metsovo
        [hotelShortDescription] => 
        [hotelVisible] => 1
        [roomID] => 4
    )

    [3] => Array
    (
        [hotelID] => 14
        [hotelcategoryID] => 7
        [hotelName] => Hotel Metropolis
        [hotelShortDescription] => 
        [hotelVisible] => 1
        [roomID] => 23
    )

    [4] => Array
    (
        [hotelID] => 14
        [hotelcategoryID] => 7
        [hotelName] => Hotel Metropolis
        [hotelShortDescription] => 
        [hotelVisible] => 1
        [roomID] => 24
    )

)
```

I have two different hotelID keys. I would like to extract only one element (the first one) where the hotelID is unique in whole array. I am trying with following code:

```
$data['uniqueHotels'] = array_map('unserialize', array_unique(array_map('serialize', $hotels)));
```

but without any luck so far.

Anyone can give me a hint?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What are you looking for? An array with unique hotelID's? What to do with duplicates? Are the other fields always the same when the hotelID is the same? (no!)

Comment: Yes, i want only the different hotelID key. First element will do. Other elements may be discharged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply loop through the array and add them to a new array, indexed by `hotelID`. This way any duplicates will just overwrite the existing value and you end up with one entry per hotel:

```
$unique = array();

foreach ($hotels as $value)
{
    $unique[$value['hotelID']] = $value;
}

$data['uniqueHotels'] = array_values($unique);
```

Answer (score 4):

If looking for the first element:

```
<?php

$hotels = array(
  array(
    'id' => 1,
    'hotelID' => 10
  ),
  array(
    'id' => 2,
    'hotelID' => 10,
  ),
  array(
    'id' => 3,
    'hotelID' => 20,
  ),
  array(
    'id' => 4,
    'hotelID' => 20,
  ),
);


function getUniqueHotels($hotels) {
  $uniqueHotels = array();

  foreach($hotels as $hotel) {
    $niddle = $hotel['hotelID'];
    if(array_key_exists($niddle, $uniqueHotels)) continue;
    $uniqueHotels[$niddle] = $hotel;
  }

  return $uniqueHotels;
}

$unique_hotels = getUniqueHotels($hotels);
print_r($unique_hotels);
```

results in:

```
Array
(
    [10] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [hotelID] => 10
        )

    [20] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [hotelID] => 20
        )

)
```

Comment: This answer should be accepted because his function returns all the array not only the unique key

Answer (score 2):

along the lines of what you're trying,

```
array_unique(array_map(function($hotel) { return $hotel['hotelID']; }, $array))
```

Comment: This works great 9 years later. Much better than all of the loops people suggest, a nice neat javascript looking one liner.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a dynmaic solution:

```
function uniqueAssocArray($array, $uniqueKey){
 $unique = array();

 foreach ($array as $value){
  $unique[$value[$uniqueKey]] = $value;
 }

 $data = array_values($unique);

 return $data;
}
```

How to use: 
`uniqueAssocArray($yourArray, 'theKey');`